# Open file with certain extension Android

Tags: android, android-intent, view

I am trying to make an app that allows the user to open and see a .stl file when he clicks on it. I've already managed to associate such a file with my app by adding the following intent-filter into my AndroidManifest.xml:
 `<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.STL" />
        <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>`
So, when the user clicks on a .STL file my app is launched. I am stuck here because I don't know how to actually display the file into my app. Can someone help?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can read the contents of the file: In the `Activity` that you are registering with your `intent-filter`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        try {
            String fileContents = getFileContents(data);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileContents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // Handle error...
        }
    }
    private String getFileContents(Uri data) throws IOException {
        InputStream fileContents = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(fileContents, writer, "US-ASCII");
        return writer.toString();
    }
    ...
}
```

This reads the contents of the `.stl` file into the variable `fileContents` and displays it in a pop-up. The code uses the `IOUtils` class from [the Apache Commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/%20Apache%20Commons%20IO). In order to integrate this class into your app, you need to download the jar for the Commons IO liblary and copy it into the `libs/` folder of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have one problem: The toast does not appear. I added the code into MainActivity and I have the following entry in the Manifest file: `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
             <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> <data android:scheme="file" /> <data android:mimeType="*/*" /> <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.STL" /> <data android:host="*" /> </intent-filter>`